# Error in rbind(info, getNamespaceInfo(env, "S3methods"))

Tags: html, r, r-markdown, rbind

I have this error when trying to compile an html document. somebody knows whats do I need to do?

I try to install and uninstall the xfun package but I don't hace idea what is failing

Comment: What are you trying to bind? Do those objects exist in the current environment? `rbind` is a function in multiple packages. If you want to make sure you're using the function from a specific package, use `::` between the package name and the function name. It looks like you're new to SO; welcome to the community! If you want great answers quickly, it's best to make your question reproducible. This includes sample data like the output from `dput()` or `reprex::reprex()` and any libraries you use. Check it out: [making R reproducible questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.